# Replace value in dataframe by value divided by mean of the entire column

Tags: r, dplyr, normalization

In need to normalise my data by dividing each value by the mean of the entire column, preferably using dplyr.

assume

```
inputs <- c(3,5,3,9,12)
mydata = data.frame(inputs)
```

I would like all the values replaced by themselves divided by the mean, which is 6.4.

Any straightforward suggestion?

Comment: `inputs / mean(inputs)`...?? Or `mydata %>% mutate(norm_inputs = inputs / mean(inputs))`

Comment: Indeed! And what if I have several columns?

Comment: Use `mutate_at`...

Comment: Found the duplicate. Just change the `funs()` to your function (`funs(. / mean(.))`)...

Comment: I can't figure out how you can apply the division to all columns of my data frame, let's say to columns 2 to 5. Can you help me?

Comment: `````mydata2 = mydata2 %>% mutate_at(vars(c(1:2)),funs(. / mean(.)))`````

Comment: If you want columns 2:5 then simply `mydata2 %>% mutate_at(vars(c(2:5)),funs(. / mean(.)))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` in `base R` for generalized approach

```
sapply(mydata, function(x) x/mean(x))
```

---

Or with `colMeans` if more than one column

```
mydata/colMeans(mydata)[col(mydata)]
```